# Storing whoami output into a variable and insert this variable into sql table's column by bash script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to have a script to help to record down the user and insert the record into a table's column. I am new to bash, so i have been trying with this method, writing it on notepad++ saving in .bat file type.

I am using this command to get whoami and set it into a variable, so that i can insert this variable into a table's column. But I cant get the whoami result and store it into a variable.

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set name=whoami

echo %name%

pause

Comment: bash and windows .cmd are totally different shells

Comment: As you have provided very little information and appear to be confused about bash and cmd, I'd like to offer you this as a complete alternative, `@ECHO %USERNAME%`

Answer (score 2):

A command substitution equivalent in batch command line (in case of multi-line only the last line will be stored in variable)

```
for /f "delims=" %n in ('whoami') do set name=%n
```

in script percent must be double

```
for /f "delims=" %%n in ('whoami') do set name=%%n
```